# Decouple WCF Service Proxy classes from Environment Endpoints

Tags: vb.net, wcf, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, mocking

The problem... I have a WCF Service, I won't waste anyone's time with copy/pasting a basic implementation here, just imagine it as beeing the standard "Echo" example you see scattered around MSDN.

Let's say I host the Service Library using IIS / a web app.  Let's also say I publish the website to varying environments - local, shared dev server, varying test servers, and of course varying live environments.  We'll also assume that the WCF gods smiled down upon us and the deployments went without a hitch =)

Now I want to write an app (lets say WPF app for some clarity).  When the app starts, I want a drop down listing all the available environments - I don't mind hardcoding or supplying (by means of a config file) those environments, but kudos points for linking any articles showing LAN discovery of deployed WCF services? ^^

When the user has selected their chosen environment, I want the app to be able to call a method on the service (in the correct environment).  Now I could do this with a big select case/if statement, instantiating the appropriate proxy class for the environment selected, calling out using the proxy class, etc.  I could even pass the class around from method to method as an object and then use select case/if statements alongside TryCast/DirectCast to ascertain which environment the provided proxy class belongs to.

But... That is ugly.  And there must be a better way.

I'm bordering on the idea of selecting an environment (none in particular, just one of them) and on the assumption that all deployments/environments have identical code, instantiate the proxy client with the endpoint details of my chosen environment.  I lose a form of type safety, but is that ok?  Is that the done way?

i.e.

```
Dim t As Binding = GetDefaultBinding()
' GetCurrentEnvironmentUri() is some function to fetch an endpoint address based on the chosen environment
Dim s As New RandomEnvironment.ProxyClient(t, New EndpointAddress(GetCurrentEnvironmentUri()))
```

Anybody had this issue?  I'm assuming it's reasonably common, the world of mock-ups are ripe these days...

Comment: Changed the question title to something that probably better reflects what I'm after - no idea what I was getting at with the previous title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for.  In the following , Wcf.IDataProvider is the contract interface and this method only supports net.tcp// transport, but you should be able to parameterize what you need to support http://.  All you have to provide is the endpoint address:

```
        ''' <summary>
    ''' Creates a Wcf Proxy for the DataAccess methods
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="p_endpointAddress">Endpoint Address to connect to</param>
    ''' <param name="p_connectTimeout">Connection timeout in seconds</param>
    ''' <param name="p_requestTimeout">Request timeout in seconds</param>
    ''' <returns></returns>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public Shared Function CreateWcfDataAccessClient(p_endpointAddress As String, p_connectTimeout As Int32, p_requestTimeout As Int32) As Wcf.IDataProvider
        Dim tempBinding As NetTcpBinding
        Dim tempAddress As EndpointAddress
        Dim tempFactory As ChannelFactory(Of Wcf.IDataProvider)
        Dim tempProxy As Wcf.IDataProvider
        tempBinding = New NetTcpBinding()
        With tempBinding
            ....
        End With
        tempAddress = New EndpointAddress(New Uri(p_endpointAddress), New SpnEndpointIdentity(""))
        With tempAddress

        End With
        tempFactory = New ChannelFactory(Of Wcf.IDataProvider)(tempBinding, tempAddress)
        With tempFactory
        End With
        tempProxy = tempFactory.CreateChannel()
        With tempProxy

        End With
        Return tempProxy

    End Function
```

Here is the service contract:

```
    <System.ServiceModel.ServiceContract()>
Public Interface IDataProvider

    <System.ServiceModel.OperationContract()>
    Function Execute(ByRef p_request() As Byte, p_useCompression As Boolean) As Byte()
End Interface
```

Comment: Hi @Robert, thanks for your answer.  I hadn't considered using Factories just yet because I was wondering how I would maintain some/any form of type safety.  In your case Wcf.IDataTransport I assume is a service contract?  If so, where is it declared - physically?  In one of the WCF environments?  On the basis the code is identical in all environments, I had considered the possibility of just picking one environment, and generating the proxy class for that environment using the endpoint details from my chosen environment... is that what this method is doing?

Comment: Also, feel free to drop the binding details for clarity if you want, personally I'm more interested in the process/pattern than the details - though of course leave it if you believe it's useful for others. =)

Comment: Yes, the IDataProvider is the service contract that handles type safety because it specifies all the methods that will be called over the WCF service.  Mine is very simple as I send serialized data back and forth allowing me to send any serializable object I want for this particular service.  I'll change the answer above to include this contract.

Comment: @Robert, I had a sneaky feeling that would be the way.  Your contract... is it defined in an assembly from which your WCF Service Contract inherits and you app references, or do you simply pick a random environment's service contract and instantiate that with a different environments binding/endpoint?

Comment: Exactly.  In my instance, I have shared assemblies on both client and server side.  I can instantiate a WCF service on the server side with very simiar code, or create the client as shown above.

Comment: Perfecto then.  It's probably very nit-picky of me, but if you could clear the With/End Withs that aren't doing anything in the code sample, I'll get this marked as an answer (just to make it clearer should someone else stumble across it) ;-)  Thanks!!

Comment: Done.  Good luck with your project.

Comment: Heh, you missed two but close enough I guess.

Comment: Yeah.  The configuring of specifically the ReaderQuotas was a pain to research and get right.  I wanted a way to create a serviceHost or client proxy without .config files.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an excellent, in depth article that's all about manually creating your own WCF proxies:

[WCF the Manual Way: The Right Way](http://code-magazine.com/Article.aspx?quickid=0809101)

This should give you the flexibility to do a lot of what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the link @Terry.  I do need to get round to doing this at some stage, but I refuse to do it until I actually _need_ to.  I think - though correct me if I'm wrong - that I probably don't need to go down this route for the question in the OP?  Having very briefly scanned that article, I also already disagree with a couple of the "Problems" listed when using the standard R-Click > Add Service Reference method, but maybe reading the whole thing will shut me up ^^.  Thanks again

Comment: Nah - you don't have to use manual proxies for what you want to do.  If you really want a user to choose the environment in a drop down, just provide multiple endpoints in your web.config and then bind to whichever service the user chooses.  Not sure how to magically discover all the environments though, and not sure why you'd even want a user to do something like this...

Comment: If you want to just be able to switch out endpoints after installation or whatever, just use Dependency Injection.  This would allow you to plug in whichever environment whenever you want to.

Comment: It's actually more for me.  =)  One of our services has some basic self-diagnostics which it stores/exposes as service operation(s).  Being able to hot-swap between environments without tedious case/if code would make life easier - for me - scanning over the services.  Plus, end user doesn't always have to be another company/person navigating to your website/customer/etc, sometimes the end user is your colleagues on the dev team =)

Comment: Hmmm, dependency injection... something to go have a look at.  Any chance you could ellaborate on that one ever so slightly for me please?

Comment: Certainly - check out Microsoft's Unity or Castle Windsor.  In general, Dependency Injection allows you to switch out components that implement the same interface by reading information in a config file.  So, if you want env A, you set up your config pointing to env A.  Then, to get env B, you just change the config to point to B.  MS Unity is probably a good place to start.  Check it out!  :)

Comment: Ah I see, so this method is more for switching environments on deployment/install as opposed to at runtime?  Not what I'm looking for in this case, but definitely worth some research on my part.  Thanks again Terry

Answer (score 1):

> I want a drop down listing all the available environments - I don't mind hardcoding or supplying (by means of a config file) those environments, but kudos points for linking any articles showing LAN discovery of deployed WCF services?

You can do that using [WCF Discovery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456782.aspx). This is a new feature in .NET 4.0 which allows a server to *broadcast* its existence, and also allows clients to send a probe message to the LAN asking which services exist for a given contract. As long as all services implement the same contract (they can have different bindings), then you can use discovery to find from the client which services can respond to it.

Comment: awesome, thank you!  I had considered implementing my own form of broadcast on the services but I wasn't sure how to do it within the WCF Service Libraries (easily achieved in the service hosts, just not the library).  They've had discovery for SQL Server and such for years, so knew MS would come up with something eventually.  Thanks for the link! =)